# Password Generator Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I decided to make a password generator to get more familiar with Python.

I had to break up the code into two boxes due to weird Stack Exchange highlighting with the triple quotes.

How would you improve this program on the grounds of:

- Readability/cleanness,
- Performance, and
- Security.

Feel free to include any other comments you have on it that may not fit into those three categories.

```
import string
import random
import secrets
import argparse
import MyFormatter

alphaL = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
alphaU = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
numeric = list(string.digits)
special = list("!@#$%^&*")
special2 = list("""~`!@#$%^&*()+=_-{}[]\|:;"'?/<>,.""")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=MyFormatter.MyFormatter,
    description="Generates a password",
    usage="",
)

parser.add_argument("-lc", "--lower", type=int, default=1, help="Minimum number of lowercase alpha characters")
parser.add_argument("-uc", "--upper", type=int, default=1, help="Minimum number of uppercase alpha characters")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--numeric", type=int, default=1, help="Minimum number of numeric characters")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--special", type=int, default=1, help="Minimum number of special characters")
parser.add_argument("-se", "--extended", action = 'store_const', default = False, const= True, help="Toggles the extendard special character subset. Passwords may not be accepted by all services")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--length", type=int, default=20, help="Length of the generated password")

args = parser.parse_args()

length = args.length

minimums = [
    args.lower,
    args.upper,
    args.numeric,
    args.special,
]

password = ""

for i in range(0, minimums[0]) :
    password += secrets.choice(alphaL)
    
for i in range(0, minimums[1]) :
    password += secrets.choice(alphaU)

for i in range(0, minimums[2]) :
    password += secrets.choice(numeric)

if args.extended :
    subset = alphaL + alphaU + numeric + special2
    for i in range(0, minimums[3]) :
        password += secrets.choice(special2)
elif minimums[3] :
    subset = alphaL + alphaU + numeric + special
    for i in range(0, minimums[3]) :
        password += secrets.choice(special)

for i in range(0, 100) :
    random.shuffle(subset)
            
for i in range(len(password), length) :
    password += secrets.choice(subset)

for i in range(0, 100) :
    password = ''.join(random.sample(password, len(password)))

print("Password: ", password)
```

Comment: I cannot import MyFormatter, is it a module of yours? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: It is a module of mine, and I can add it if you'd like, but it just does some formatting for the help command and doesn't add anything to the program itself. I'll try to remember to replace "MyFormater.MyFormater" with "HelpFormatter"

Answer (score 4):

Already pointed out by other users

- There is no need to make lists from the strings as any sequence will do
- `minimums` - you make bad names where the existing names were better

## The if clause

```
if args.extended :
    subset = alphaL + alphaU + numeric + special2
    for i in range(0, minimums[3]) :
        password += secrets.choice(special2)
elif minimums[3] :
    subset = alphaL + alphaU + numeric + special
    for i in range(0, minimums[3]) :
        password += secrets.choice(special)
```

is erroneous. The check for `elif minimums[3]` shall be replaced by an `else:`

Also - just because you already switch on `args.extended` you are not required to pack all variation on that argument in there.
You prepare subset for the logically next function (choice from compound set) before even performing the current one (choice from special).
That results in less readability. There is nothing wrong in switching two times if required. However in this case you should simply switch

```
if args.extended:
    special = """~`!@#$%^&*()+=_-{}[]\|:;"'?/<>,."""
else:
    special = "!@#$%^&*"
```

Then the choice from special/special2 collapses to the standard pattern.

## Names

It was already mentioned that the minimum list is a name worse than the args attributes (which could be even more descriptive).
Also the names for your imports are bad and camel-cased. why not simply follow the existing naming scheme?

```
ascii_lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase
```

or even more straight

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase
from string import digits
```

An extra bad name is `subset`

```
subset = alphaL + alphaU + numeric + special
```

which is clearly a union or superset

## The standard pattern

You do

```
for i in range(0, minimums[0]) :
    password += secrets.choice(alphaL)
```

the recommended way to character wise join a string is

```
password += "".join(secrets.choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range (0, args.lower)
```

## Cargo cult

You do

```
for i in range(0, 100) :
    random.shuffle(subset)
```

which is pointless. It is pointless to shuffle a 100 times. there is no extra quality in randomness compared to a single shuffle.
It is even more pointless to do that before apply `secrets.choice(subset)`. You could safely sort subset before choice().

## Final shuffle

You do

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    print("Password: ", password)
    password = ''.join(random.sample(password, len(password)))
```

which I interpret as final shuffle to eliminate the order of the subsets `ascii_lowercase`, `ascii_uppercase`, ...

Again you shuffle a 100 times which will not add any value compared to a single shuffle. To be cryptographically safe you should implement a shuffle based on `secrets.choice`.

Comment: If clause: I see how that is cleaner, thank you.
Names: once again thank you.
Pattern: Fundamentally, why is this better? Behind the scenes, what's the difference? 
Cargo Cult/Final shuffle: I assumed a few more shuffles (Since the program is still effectively instant) would be btter, which I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: join is more efficient - see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312099/why-is-join-faster-than-in-python. that is neglible if joining two strings but makes a difference if joining in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

### Redundant casts

```
alphaL = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
alphaU = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
numeric = list(string.digits)
special = list("!@#$%^&*")
special2 = list("""~`!@#$%^&*()+=_-{}[]\|:;"'?/<>,.""")
```

Are you sure that casts to `list` are needed here? For example, `string.ascii_lowercase` is a `str`, which is already a sequence of strings (each one character). `secrets.choice` [says](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/secrets.html#secrets.choice):

> Return a randomly-chosen element from a non-empty sequence.

So it will be able to handle the strings directly. Casting to a `list` is actually regressive, since `list` is mutable but these sequences should not be.

### Latin

It's really pedantic, but `maximums` should be `maxima`.

### Named arguments

There's no point to the `minimums` list. Every time you reference it, you reference one of its elements by index; so just reference the arguments from which it was initialized and get rid of the list.

### Partially insecure entropy

Whereas you use `secrets` for some entropy, you use `random` in other cases, namely

```
random.shuffle(subset)
random.sample(password, len(password))
```

This is not secure and needs to be replaced with `secrets` calls.

Comment: Redundant casts: I didn't know python handled strings that way. Thank you
Latin: Thank you
Redundant predicate: If a user requests 0 special characters it would return false. But then that doesn't generate the subset currently which needs to be fixed
partially insecure: To my knowledge, there's no shuffle and sample available within secrets and I see no documentation of such methods.

Comment: I misinterpreted what you're doing with `minimums`; I've edited my answer to indicate that it shouldn't exist at all.

Comment: _there's no shuffle and sample available within secrets_ - correct; you would need to implement equivalent behaviour from the primitives available in `secrets`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Possible bug

It looks like if `args.extended` is False (the default) and `args.special` is set to zero (using -s 0), then `subset` won't get defined and the subsequent call `random.shuffle(subset)` would throw an exception.

#### clarity

What is the benefit of the list `minimums`?  `args.lower` is clearer than `minimums[0]`. Better yet, the `dest` argument to `parser.add_argument` lets you specify the a more descriptive name of the variable, like so:

```
parser.add_argument("-lc", "--lower", dest="min_lowercase",
                    type=int, default=1, 
                    help="Minimum number of lowercase alpha characters")
```

Comment: Possible Bug: Yes, that is an issue, thanks for pointing it out.

Clarity: It was from my original approach, which I decided against. Then when changing over to the current itteration I didn't think about it.